# NT authentification on domain in ASP.NET web site 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, dns, window

Hi I would like use Window NT authentification on domain in ASP.NET 2.0 web site.

I would  like force user input credentials when he first visit my web site. Web site will be  used only on intranet.

I know domain is in format x.y.com.

I add to web.confing element:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

My first problem is:

1. But I don’t how show clasic window
   formular for input user credentials when user visit a web site.

I mean this form:

http://blumenthalit.net/blog/Lists/Posts/Attachments/54/image_2.png

2 And my second problem is authentification on domain. I google it and only this part code work for me.

```
public class WinAPI
{
    // Use NTLM security provider to check
    public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0x0;
    // To validate the account
    public const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 0x3;

    // API declaration for validating user credentials
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, 
        string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out int phToken);
    //API to close the credential token
    [DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "CloseHandle")]
    public static extern long CloseHandle(long hObject);
};




   int hToken = 2;
        bool ret = WinAPI.LogonUser("userName", "domain.example.com", "password", WinAPI.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK,
        WinAPI.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
        out hToken);

        if (ret == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Valid Windows domain User ");
            WinAPI.CloseHandle(hToken);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Not an valid Windows domain User ");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The main point of Windows authentication is, for intranets, that a login box does *not* appear, users authenticate automatically using their domain credentials. Why on earth would you want to force users to type in their user name and password, probably in clear text unless you're going to install an SSL certificate, and then attempt to impersonate them manually?

The only way to do what you want is to turn on [Basic Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292114%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in IIS (Instructions for [IIS7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009%28WS.10%29.aspx)/[IIS6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/abbca505-6f63-4267-aac1-1ea89d861eb4.mspx?mfr=true)). However if you do so you need an SSL certificate to protect the usernames and passwords in transit. I strongly recommend you do not go this route.

Answer (score 1):

I would add to @blowdart's answer that you could also use forms authentication along with the [LdapMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.security.ldapmembershipprovider.aspx) to authenticate against Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this link, it should tell you how to deny access to anonymous users, so you should get a popup.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/12/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application.aspx

```
 <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
         <authorization>
             <deny users="?"/>
          </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Note that the <deny users=”?”/> directive within the <authorization> section above is what tells ASP.NET to deny access to the application to all “anonymous” users to the site (the “?” character means anonymous user).  This forces Windows to authenticate the user, and ensures that the username is always available from code on the server.
```